# How do you Restrict a warehouse to Resize to role in snowflake

Tags: resize, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[How to disable the resize access to role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNsJV.png)

Answer (score 0):

As long as user doesn't have the MODIFY grant for WAREHOUSE they won't be able to change the size. The option does appear there, but once clicked on a Resize value an error message will appear like this:

[image]

See documentation here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#virtual-warehouse-privileges

Comment: If you are granting only usage privilege to the warehouse they can able to resize as well. I am able to restrict the user to access the warehouse.

Comment: I've granted a role the usage grant on warehouse and I was not able to resize. Only by granting modify on warehouse I was able to resize the warehouse.